# How to concatenate text in different lines If they are next to each other

Tags: python, pandas

So I have this TXT with the following sample of text:

```
3f064f5dc6d9054cae0602d922cfb3bc.jpg
c471d894b3384dbb5becfbf35886614c.jpg

44b703af3547891a277fe4b2971a0e8d.jpg
ca45e2c73156b8513aa4c286abac2191.jpg
ff286b1f745a235426f28f5edbdd2df6.jpg

70fe48160a3745fc9d963297d6a7e819.jpg
cb017ddb752ad8fb92f22f3cc0c0498a.jpg
```

I would like to concatenate all the text that is in the contiguous line into one line separated by an "OR" in python.

According to the sample above the output is 3 lines:

3f064f5dc6d9054cae0602d922cfb3bc.jpg OR c471d894b3384dbb5becfbf35886614c.jpg

44b703af3547891a277fe4b2971a0e8d.jpg OR ca45e2c73156b8513aa4c286abac2191.jpg OR ff286b1f745a235426f28f5edbdd2df6.jpg

70fe48160a3745fc9d963297d6a7e819.jpg OR cb017ddb752ad8fb92f22f3cc0c0498a.jpg

How can this be done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why is this tagged with pandas? does that mean you want the output in a series/dataframe?

Comment: If Pandas has an easy way to do it I belive that converting the txt file to a dataframe would be a possibility yes.

Comment: What happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem?

Comment: I didn't even know how to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

for v, g in groupby(map(str.strip, open("your_file.txt", "r")), lambda k: k != ""):
    if v:
        print(" OR ".join(g))
```

Prints:

```
3f064f5dc6d9054cae0602d922cfb3bc.jpg OR c471d894b3384dbb5becfbf35886614c.jpg
44b703af3547891a277fe4b2971a0e8d.jpg OR ca45e2c73156b8513aa4c286abac2191.jpg OR ff286b1f745a235426f28f5edbdd2df6.jpg
70fe48160a3745fc9d963297d6a7e819.jpg OR cb017ddb752ad8fb92f22f3cc0c0498a.jpg
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thks

Answer (score 0):

Just split the content by `\n\n`

```py
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    content = f.read()

lines = [line.rstrip().replace('\n', ' OR ') for line in content.split('\n\n')]
```

```
for line in lines:
    print(line)

3f064f5dc6d9054cae0602d922cfb3bc.jpg OR c471d894b3384dbb5becfbf35886614c.jpg
44b703af3547891a277fe4b2971a0e8d.jpg OR ca45e2c73156b8513aa4c286abac2191.jpg OR ff286b1f745a235426f28f5edbdd2df6.jpg
70fe48160a3745fc9d963297d6a7e819.jpg OR cb017ddb752ad8fb92f22f3cc0c0498a.jpg
```